# firebase image retrieval in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

The problem I am facing is that on selecting an Image from the Gallery using Gallery Intent, though the image is stored on Firebase Storage but is not displayed in the ImageView. Instead, the Placeholder disappears and nothing is visible. P.S I am new to Android and Firebase.

Attaching the Screenshot of the same.

[before uploading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNW8b.png)

[After uploading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqqfp.png)

**Following is my code:**

```
public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

Button selectImage, save_data_editProfile;
EditText editText, editText2;
ImageView imageView;
private StorageReference mStorage;
private Toolbar mToolBar;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;
private ImageButton mphotoPickerButton;
private String currentUserEmail;
private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
private DatabaseReference mCurrentUserDatabaseReference;
private Context mView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

    //selectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectImage);
    save_data_editProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_data_editProfile);
    //imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


    mView = EditProfile.this;
    initializeScreen();
    openImageSelector();
    initializeUserInfo();


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data){

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(); //make global
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, requestCode, data);

    if(requestCode ==GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        mProgress.setMessage("Uploading...");
        mProgress.show();

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //Keep all images for a specific chat grouped together
        final String imageLocation = "Photos/profile_picture/" + currentUserEmail;
        final String imageLocationId = imageLocation + "/" + uri.getLastPathSegment();
        final String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child(imageLocation).child(uniqueId + "/profile_pic");
        final String downloadURl = filepath.getPath();
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                //create a new message containing this image
                addImageToProfile(downloadURl);
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

}

public void addImageToProfile(final String imageLocation){
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mCurrentUserDatabaseReference
            .child("profilePicLocation").setValue(imageLocation).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                            .getReference().child(imageLocation);

                    //Picasso.get().load(imageLocation).into(imageView);



                    Glide.with(mView)
                            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                            .load(storageRef)
                            .bitmapTransform(new CropSquareTransformation(mView))
                            .into(imageView);
                }
            }
    );

}

public void openImageSelector(){

    mphotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mphotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
            //mView = view;
        }
    });
}

private void initializeUserInfo(){
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mCurrentUserDatabaseReference
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    try{
                        if(user.getProfilePicLocation() != null){
                            StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                    .getReference().child(user.getProfilePicLocation());



                            Glide.with(mView)
                                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                                    .load(storageRef)
                                    .bitmapTransform(new CropSquareTransformation(mView))
                                    .into(imageView);
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}

private void initializeScreen(){
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    currentUserEmail = EmailEncoding.commaEncodePeriod(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
    mCurrentUserDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase
            .getReference().child(Constants.USERS_LOCATION
                    + "/" + currentUserEmail);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `addImageToProfile(taskSnapshot.downloadURl.toString());` on your OnSuccessListener and

```
Glide.with(mView)
       .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
       .load(imageLocation)
       .bitmapTransform(new CropSquareTransformation(mView))
       .into(imageView);
```